# Finding common values of two columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create the query where I can obtain the locations that are common to two countries on a specific day.

I have tried using JOIN to obtain the common countries of USA and IND on Tuesdays, but have not succeeded.

USA->IND,UK,GER

IND->USA,UK,GER,ITA

**FINAL RESULT:** UK, GER

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
from_location varchar(256) NOT NULL,
to_location varchar(256) NOT NULL,
day varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `test` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `test` MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('USA', 'IND', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('UK', 'IND', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('IND', 'GER', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('GER', 'USA', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('GER', 'UK', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('USA', 'UK', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('IND', 'ITA', 'TUE');
INSERT INTO `test` (`from_location`,`to_location`,`day`) VALUES ('IND', 'POL', 'WED');
```

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
SELECT
t1.from_location
FROM
  test4 t1
JOIN
  test4 t2
    ON  t2.from_location = t2.to_location
    AND t1.from_location = t1.to_location
WHERE
   (t1.from_location = "IND"
   OR t1.to_location = "IND")
AND
   (t1.from_location = "USA"
   OR t1.to_location = "USA")
AND
    t1.day = "TUE"
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried self join however, I'm not getting the intended results.

Comment: Pls show your attempt in your question!

Comment: What results do you get instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT location_b 
  FROM
     ( SELECT from_location location_a, to_location location_b FROM test WHERE day = 'tue' AND from_location IN ('ind','usa')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT to_location,from_location FROM test WHERE day = 'tue' AND to_location IN ('ind','usa')
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY location_b 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location_a) = 2
```